# TypeError: video_stream() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, tkinter, opencv

Написал интерфейс для программы используя для него отдельный класс. Пытался в отдельный фрейм (место для видео на интерфейсе) вывести видео. Нашел код, который выводит видео в Tkinter, но при добавлении его в класс не видел переменной в методе def. Добавил self и выдал ошибку.
Вот код, который нашел:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2


root = Tk()
# Create a frame
app = Frame(root, bg="white")
app.grid()
# Create a label in the frame
lmain = Label(app)
lmain.grid()

# Capture from camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# function for video streaming
def video_stream():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(1, video_stream) 

video_stream()
root.mainloop()
```

При переводе в класс:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2

class GUT:

    root = Tk()
    # Create a frame
    app = Frame(root, bg="white")
    app.grid()
    # Create a label in the frame
    lmain = Label(app)
    lmain.grid()

    # Capture from camera
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("8-bit trip.mp4")

    # function for video streaming
    def video_stream(self):

        _, frame = self.cap.read()
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        self.lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        self.lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        self.lmain.after(1, self.video_stream)

    video_stream()

    root.mainloop()
```

(self добавил т.к. не видел переменные)
Как исправить ошибку или есть альтернативный вариант для привязки видео к отдельному фрейму в интерфейсе.

Comment: Код класса как-то очень криво написан, сначала нужно его в нормальный вид привести. Сейчас довольно большая часть кода непонятно где висит, видимо в коде класса, а не экземпляра класса, что мягко говоря нехорошо для интерактивного кода - теряется контроль над процессом исполнения кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сначала нужно ознакомиться с теорией - как должен выглядеть класс в Python, и как он работает, попробовать написать несколько классов без tkinter.
2. После этого нужно подумать - нужен ли вам класс вообще? Часто это совершенно излишне. Если у вас на весь код одна функция, и вы зачем-то этот код хотите обернуть в класс, то вы что-то делаете не так.
3. Дополнительно ко второму пункту: не нужно бездумно весь код собирать в один класс, иначе у вас получится классический ["божественный объект"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82). Это не ООП, это [карго культ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82) ООП. Не нужно думать, что просто добавление в ваш код классов сделает ваш код лучше.
4. В целом, ООП - это один из инструментов структурирования и уменьшения сложности кода. Если вы просто обернете весь код в один класс - это никак не уменьшит сложность кода (скорее увеличит).

К прочтению: [Перестаньте писать классы (Джэк Дидрих)](https://habr.com/ru/post/140581/)

---

Если уж сильно хочется обернуть код в класс, то код верхнего уровня (код вне функций, кроме импортов) нужно перенести в метод `__init__` класса, тогда этот код будет выполняться при создании объекта. Поля, которые должны быть доступны из методов класса нужно записывать через `self`. Методы также должны вызываться от `self` (см. вызов метода `video_stream` в примере ниже). **Само по себе такое оборачивание бессмысленно, см. объяснение в начале.**

Грубый пример такого "оборачивания":

```
class GUT:
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        # Create a frame
        app = Frame(root, bg="white")
        app.grid()
        # Create a label in the frame
        self.lmain = Label(app)
        self.lmain.grid()

        # Capture from camera
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("8-bit trip.mp4")
        
        self.video_stream()

        root.mainloop()

    # function for video streaming
    def video_stream(self):
        _, frame = self.cap.read()
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        self.lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        self.lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        self.lmain.after(1, self.video_stream)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUT()
```

---

Для tkinter есть более-менее общепринятый подход - для окна или фрейма (если фрейм работает более-менее независимо других частей окна) делать свой класс, при этом класс наследуется от класса окна (`Tk` или `Toplevel`) или фрейма.

Вариант с наследованием от `Tk`:

```
class GUT(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Create a frame
        app = Frame(self, bg="white")
        app.grid()
        # Create a label in the frame
        self.lmain = Label(app)
        self.lmain.grid()

        # Capture from camera
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("8-bit trip.mp4")
        
        self.video_stream()

    # function for video streaming
    def video_stream(self):

        _, frame = self.cap.read()
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        self.lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        self.lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        self.lmain.after(1, self.video_stream)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUT().mainloop()
```

Вариант с наследованием от `Frame`:

```
class GUT(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Create a label in the frame
        self.lmain = Label(self)
        self.lmain.grid()

        # Capture from camera
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("8-bit trip.mp4")
        
        self.video_stream()

    # function for video streaming
    def video_stream(self):

        _, frame = self.cap.read()
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        self.lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        self.lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        self.lmain.after(1, self.video_stream)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = GUT(root, bg="white")
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Также можно пробовать реализовать нечто вроде [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) - тогда у вас отдельный класс (view) должен отвечать только за создание графического интерфейса (части графического интерфейса) и взаимодействие с пользователем, отдельный (model) - за хранение состояния приложения или части приложения, отдельный (controller) - за выполнение какой-то полезной работы, например того же получения данных с камеры. Это имеет смысл делать для сложных многооконных/многофреймовых приложений. Для простого однооконного приложения такое разделение скорее всего будет излишне, и возможно приведет к усложнению кода.

Comment: Нет ли тут опечатки `GUT().mainloop()` (вариант наследования от Frame)? :)

Comment: @gil9red, точно, поправил